# Why accepting edits with edit privilege should not be immediate

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

If a user suggests an edit, two users with access to the review queue are necessary to validate the edit, even if the first user has the "edit applied immediately" privilege. Why is that so? Users with edit privileges can override the edit, do the same edit themselves, and get it applied immediately. However, if instead they accept the edit, it is necessary to wait for another user approval.

Is there a reason to keep this feature?

There are some answers to this question in [MetaSE: Why do we need multiple approvers for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-do-we-need-multiple-approvers-for-suggested-edits)

Comment: Might be more appropriate for [meta.SE] since this is a general feature of how suggested edits on SE sites work and nothing specific to physics.SE

Comment: why would someone override the valid edit of another user just to have it applied immediately?  This must happen very rarely…

Comment: There are also cross-site duplicates on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) (though I don't have the notes to quickly find them). [A starting point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332651/is-this-how-reject-and-edit-is-supposed-to-work/332655#332655).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero from time to time that happens, you want to edit something and a user has already done it but as suggested edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, this question is actually concerns MetaSE, so after some research I will self-answer it. There are indeed some answers to this question in [MetaSE: Why do we need multiple approvers for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386316/why-is-it-that-a-reviewer-with-full-edit-privileges-cannot-single-handedly-appro) The reason summary was given by another comment in [duplicate question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386316/why-is-it-that-a-reviewer-with-full-edit-privileges-cannot-single-handedly-appro) by @Spevacus:

> The TL;DR is... Quality. It's extremely easy to hit "Approve" on an edit that might not be that great of an edit. It's less likely that two people robotically click "Approve" on a bad edit. It's much less likely that someone hits one of the improvement options and actually makes changes themselves and those end up being bad changes.